# Displaying UILabel dynamcially from the NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a mutable array as below

```
 labelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One”, @“Two”, @“Three", nil];
```

I want to display all the list array values as individual label. This is like displaying the `UILabel` dynamically using the array values. What i did is as below,

```
 int count=20;
 for(int i = 0; i < [labelArrays count]; i++){
 label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
 label1.text = [labelArrays componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
 label1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.643 green:0.643 blue:0.639 alpha:1];
 label1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
 label1.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
 count+=20;
 [self addSubview:label1];
}
```

Here I can only display all the array values inside the single label. How can i display the array values in multiple labels dynamically.

```
//viewcontroller

myView.label1.frame =CGRectMake(588,200,200,28);
```

Comment: What's your issue? What's nor working? You didn't set a frame for `label1`. What's its frame?

Comment: Create a new label and update the label frame with each iteration, with above code you are adding multiple labels over one another.

Comment: what label1 is,  is it retain property?

Comment: Remove the for-loop and add a frame to your label.

Comment: @Larme The issue is, the elements of array are not displaying as separate UILabels. They are merged together in a single UILabel. But what i need is to display the array elements in a separate labels. Between this code is in view and I am calling the frame in another controller

Comment: @PradeepSingh hope nearly, you got my issue. I can iterate the array into label but how am supposed to present the array elements in individual  labels

Comment: @teamnorge Yes, the label1 is a UILabel with the retain property.

Comment: @Sabarish then, it means that you add same UILabel as subView just re- initializing it before adding. You need to do:  UILabel *label1 = [UILabel new]; To keep references you can, for example, create retain array and put your UILabels there. And of course do not forget to set UILabel frame as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a public method for `view` in which you are willing to add the `UILabel`, pass a `CGRect` to that method and then according to your design, with each iteration update the x coordinate or y coordinate. Follow the below steps:

```
// code in your viewcontroller
[myView designYourMultipleLabelsWithStartingFrame:CGRectMake(588,200,200,28)]; // pass the frame of the first label.
```

Now add the multiple `UILabel` in your view class, let's assume you have set `labelArrays`.

```
// code in view class
-(void) designYourMultipleLabelsWithStartingFrame:(CGRect) frame{

   float xCoordinate = frame.origin.x;
   float yCoordinate = frame.origin.y;

   for(int counter = 0; counter < [labelArrays count]; counter++){
      UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,labelWidth,labelHeight)];
      label.text = [labelArrays objectAtIndex:counter];
      [self addSubview:label];
      // update the x coordinate or y coordinate according to your design. Let's say we need the labels in vertical order, so update the y Coordinate by labelHeight and gap between two labels.
      yCoordinate = yCoordinate + labelHeight + gapBetweenTwoLabels.
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: In the same way instead of `UILabel`, if I add `UIButton`, How I am supposed to populate the buttons? I tried with `setTag` and passed the counter value but didn't work.

Comment: You have to use setTitle:forState: of UIButton to set the title of the UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

your coding is fine , but you are not added the frame , try this

```
label1 =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,count,aslikeyourwidth,aslikeyourheight)];
```

Comment: @sabarish -- give the feedback it is easy to optimize the answer

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to mention the above code is in view and i had mentioned the frame in another controller. I can able to display the label but not as separate label. It has merged in a single label and displaying all the array elements

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought - would you not be better using a tableview to show the array?

It looks like you may need to just handle their position on the view as the code looks like it is adding the labels but it is placing them over each other.

Comment: It wont be as simple as that unfortunately because in order for your labels to not overlap each other then they each need individual frames. So within your for loop you are going to have to add to the frame position for each label.